# OnInit retrieving Service property which is not yet loaded

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I am very new to Angular 2+ (about a week), and I have an issue regarding the observables part.

I have this Service:

```
export class GetProductsService {

  allProducts;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe({
      next: data => this.allProducts = data,
      error: err => console.log(err)
    });
  }

  getAllProducts() {
    return this.allProducts;
  }
```

In the constructor I make a get request to retrieve some fake "products".

The products that I retrieve, I store in a property, so that I can easier use other functions on the property in the future.

Now here is my issue: I have this component

```
export class AllProductsComponent implements OnInit {

allProducts: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private productsService: GetProductsService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.allProducts = this.productsService.getAllProducts();
  }


}
```

That retrieves the products property from the ProductService OnInit, however considering that it is an observable, when the other component tries to retrieve the allProducts property, it is not yet fully loaded from the observable stream.

How would this be solved, I can see this being a frequent issue, which is why I'm also asking for more of a general better understanding of the topic. I understand that It is async which i understand what it is.

**What I have tried**:

I tried just having the Service return the Observable instead of setting its own state, however then when i implement a function to retrieve a specific product, i have to make the HTTP call again, instead of using the internal State.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Can you show us where you import the service? if the service is @Injectable (providedIn: Root) you have to be sure that service is injected before you use it in the component and not at the same time as in your code above.

Comment: Yes it is providedIn: Root. How could I make sure it is injected before the other component calls it? @Lievno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the observable from the service instead if you want to be notified of when the response is returned.

You can cache the response on the first response if you want to avoid making another http request in the lifetime of the app.

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class GetProductsService {

  private cache = {
    allProducts;
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllProducts() {
    if (this.cache.allProducts) {
      return of(this.cache.allProducts);
    }

    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').pipe(
      tap(response => this.cache.allProducts = response)
    );
  }
}
```

You should then subscribe to this function in your component.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.productsService.getAllProducts().subscribe(products => {
    this.allProducts = products;
  });
}
```

Note - this is a very simple form of state management, and I have demonstrated this pattern as a way to help you learn how to work with observables. There are more advanced state management patterns and tools that you will come across in time.

Comment: Ah yes I like that cache part! Because I will have a getSpecificProduct() method which is why I did not want to make an HTTP call for every method. 

Could you just briefly explain what .pipe and tap does here? 

I will research that a little more. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Pipe allows you to perform a series of actions between the original observable and the subscriber. In my experience the most common actions are `map`, `tap`, and `switchMap`. Here `tap` allows you to do something with the observable result (a side-effect) and implicitly pass it on to the next pipe operator / subscriber.

Comment: All rxjs operators can be found here: https://rxjs.dev/api (second section). As you can see, there are quite a few.

Comment: Aha, so you can say that pipe kind of acts like a middleware, before the subscriber gets it? And the tap allows you to tap into the data that comes from the observer, and do something with it, within the middleware, also before the subscriber gets it?

Comment: Exactly. `tap` used to be called `do` - as in "do something" I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

I use an API service like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  private setHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
    const headersConfig = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    };

//...

    return new HttpHeaders(headersConfig);
  }

  private formatErrors(errorResponse: any) {
    return Observable.throw(errorResponse.error);
  }

  get(path: string, params: any = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.api_url}${path}`, { headers: this.setHeaders(), params: params })
    .catch(this.formatErrors);
  }
}
```

And use it like this in my ItemService:

```
 query(itemSlug: string): Observable<{ items: Item[] }> {   
    return this.apiService
      .get('/items/' + itemSlug);
  }
```

And in my contoller, I user the ItemService like so:

```
this.itemsService.query(this.item.slug).subscribe(data => {
  this.items = data.items;
});
```

For more information on this approach, please see https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app

Comment: Looks interesting! Thank you for taking the time to reply! :)